# Windows Media Player not working correctly on a new thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have made a Music class as follows :

```
public class Music
{
    public void StartMusic()
    {                        
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = "Resources/music3.MID";
        wplayer.controls.play();                            
    }
}
```

On the Main Screen, I start a new thread as follows :

```
Music music = new Music();
thread = new Thread( new ThreadStart(music.StartMusic));            
thread.Start();
```

Now, the music plays as desired on starting the screen but the problem is that as soon as I interact on the UI, click a button or an expander, the music thread stops. Interestingly, if I use SoundPlayer instead of MusicPlayer, everything works OK. Here is the code for SoundPlayer :

```
public void StartMusic()
{
    SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer("Resources/music1.wav");
    sound.PlayLooping();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem just by creating the WindowsMediaPlayer object outside the startMusic() method. Such a silly mistake.